# How to change the default error message on browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, jquery-plugins

How to change the "***This page requirs ActiveX for xml parsing enable ActiveX on your browser***" above error message in my browser.is there any other jquery method to change the error message.

Comment: when yu get this error?

Comment: In Page load,when browser dont have the Active X Control enabled.